# MySQL date format change

Tags: mysql, date

Hi I have data I load to a varchar field  in format 8/21/2013, I need it to string to date and put it in the correct format 2013-08-21. Ive tried string to date and date format but there must be a way to specify that it is in %m/%d/%y and in need it %y-%m-%d. right now I get this error [Err] 1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '08-21-2013'
(I concated a 0 incase it didnt recognize the above month)

Answer (score 2):

You switched days and month. There's no month number 21, that's why you get this error. Try

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('8/21/2013', '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function