# Codeigniter - Exporting table records to CSV with Date Format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

here I am exporting the table result in CSV format and I want to format the date column something like this **2017-08-31, 13:10:12**

anyone help me to modify this mySql query

```
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_on,'%Y-%m-%d , %H:%i:%s') AS OrderDate,transaction.order_id,transaction.payment_method FROM transaction";
```

and here is my Export to CSV function

```
function ExportCSV()
{
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $delimiter = ",";
    $newline = "\r\n";
    $filename = "lugmah_sales_report.csv";
    $query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_on,'%Y-%m-%d , %H:%i:%s') AS OrderDate,transaction.order_id,transaction.payment_method FROM transaction";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($result, $delimiter, $newline);
    force_download($filename, $data);
}
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL date format change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463001/mysql-date-format-change)

Comment: @RealCheeseLord i checked with that query but in CSV/Excel file the Date column shows Blank value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arsee, Better you try with This query `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_on`), '%e %b %Y') AS OrderDate,`

Answer (score 1):

Change your query like this

$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_on,'%Y-%m-%d , %H:%i:%s') AS OrderDate FROM transaction";

Note: Space between Order Date should be removed

Comment: Then check for any syntax error in your export function